# MacOS: How to split same application into separate instances

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

In Windows there is an option that separates same application instances into separate "icons" in taskbar. This is super convenient because now I can click on one Chrome instance and the second one will keep in background without jumping forward and show up in my second screen.

it doesn't seem to be doable in MacOS and whenever I click Chrome all windows show up, which is pretty annoying. Is there a way to separate different Chrome windows to separate instances?

BTW I already unchecked 'Minimize windows into application icons' but I don't think it's related.

Comment: You're ***really*** fighting a paradigm difference between Mac & PC app instances with this one. The Mac *does not want you to do this* & will fight you if you try. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338551/is-there-a-way-to-open-separate-instance-of-chrome-where-cmd-q-doesnt-close-all [second answer] for how to actually do it… by compiling your own version & running it as a distinct separate app.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin I give up! But I have a better solution: I'll use Chrome for work and Firefox for more personal tabs (guess I can't totally get rid of them on a work computer).

Comment: You can open a second instance of an app from the command line with `open -n -a app-name`

Comment: That `open` trick sounds cool, but doesn't work w/ Chrome.  It just opens a new window in the same app (for me).